# How to switch between different properties files based on request at runtime?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

Currently I read properties file by defining a global element like;

```
>   <configuration-properties doc:name="Local Configuration Properties"
>       doc:id="899a4f41-f036-4262-8cf2-3b0062dbd740"
> file="config\local_app.properties" />
```

But this is not enough for me
 when try to deal different clients dynamically.

**Usecase**

I need to pick right configuration file when request comes in. That is, for different clients I have different properties file.( their credentials and all different). When request is received from listener, i'll check with clientid header and based on that value, i'll pick right configuration file. My properties files are added to different location.(Doing deployment through openshift.) Not within mule app. So, we don't need to redeploy the application each time, when our application supports new client.

So, in this case, how to define ? and how to pick right properties file?

eg:

> ```
> clientid =google, i have properties file defined for google-app.properties.
> clientid=yahoo, i have properties file defined for yahoo-app.properties.
> clientid=? I'll add properties file ?-app.properties later
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties files are read **deployment time**. That means that if you change the values, you to redeploy the application to read the new ones. System properties need a restart of the Mule Runtime instance to be set. And Runtime Manager properties need a restart of the application. In any case the application will restart. Properties can not be used as you want.

There is no way to use configuration properties dynamically like that. What you could do is to create a module using Mule SDK that read properties files and returns the resulting set of properties, so you can assign the result to a variable, and use the values as variables. You will need to find a way to update the values. Maybe set a flow with a scheduler to read the values with a fixed frequency.

Comment: Im going with a option like defining my  variables in the properties with a prefix/suffix. and computing that at runtime based on request and pick values. eg: in my properties file; clientA_username=mary,clientB_username=john. in the flow,<![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 "x-username" :  <calculate username property>
}]]]>